# Query specific column for 2 different values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I don't have much experience with database so this might look silly.

I just can't query the same column for 2 different values.

This is what I am trying:

```
where  b.idIndice = 10 and b.idIndice = 20
```

I have both values in this column

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide me the sample data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL b WHERE b.idIndice IN (10, 20)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
WHERE b.idIndice = 10 OR b.idIndice = 20
```

Or

```
WHERE b.idIndice IN(10, 20)
```

A value can't be equal to 10 and to 20 at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

use in ()

where b.idIndice in (10,20)

refer here

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/in.php

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE  b.idIndice = 10 OR b.idIndice = 20
```